# Nested IF returns 0 when dynamic named range added

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I've got a nested IF statement that seems to be working fine.

```
=IF(INDEX(F$3:F$523,MATCH(OFFSET(Z6,0,L6-2),OUID,0))="X", OFFSET(Z6,0,L6-2,), IF(INDEX(F$3:F$523,MATCH(OFFSET(Z6,0,L6-3),OUID,0))="X", OFFSET(Z6,0,L6-3), IF(INDEX(F$3:F$523,MATCH(OFFSET(Z6,0,L6-4),OUID,0))="X", OFFSET(Z6, 0, L6-4), IF(INDEX(F$3:F$523,MATCH(OFFSET(Z6,0,L6-5),OUID,0))="X", OFFSET(Z6,0,L6-5), IF(INDEX(F$3:F$523,MATCH(OFFSET(Z6,0,L6-6),OUID,0))="X", OFFSET(Z6,0,L6-6), "ERROR")))))
```

Where OUID is a dynamic named range defined as:

```
=OFFSET('DLH'!$B$3,0,0,COUNTA('DLH'!$B:$B),1)
```

This works as expected and returns the appropriate cell. However, if I try to replace the F$3:F$523 element of the formula with the dynamic named range called "Report" defined as:

```
=OFFSET('DLH'!$F$3,0,0,COUNTA('DLH'!$F:$F),1)
```

It starts returning "0" instead of the text string in the cell. The new non-working formula looks like:

```
=IF(INDEX(Report,MATCH(OFFSET(Z5,0,L5-2),OUID,0))="X", OFFSET(Z5,0,L5-2,), IF(INDEX(Report,MATCH(OFFSET(Z5,0,L5-3),OUID,0))="X", OFFSET(Z5,0,L5-3), IF(INDEX(Report,MATCH(OFFSET(Z5,0,L5-4),OUID,0))="X", OFFSET(Z5, 0, L5-4), IF(INDEX(Report,MATCH(OFFSET(Z5,0,L5-5),OUID,0))="X", OFFSET(Z5,0,L5-5), IF(INDEX(Report,MATCH(OFFSET(Z5,0,L5-6),OUID,0))="X", OFFSET(Z5,0,L5-6), "ERROR")))))
```

All both dynamic named ranges do is allow for the number of rows to change. The formula above is in cell F5. I thought it might be a problem because the Report dynamic named range refers to the same column as the original cell but even if I move the formula to a different cell it still returns a 0.

When I use the evaluate function in excel on this and compare it to the working version, it all seems to work fine, it even produces the correct final cell reference, it's just at the last stage that it fails and returns 0.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: My guess is there might be different number of cells populated in $B:$B compared to $F:$F.  I would use the same column for your countA to keep it consistant.

Comment: That was it. Thank you. If you add that to the answers below I'll accept the answer to give you the credit.

Comment: I couldn't find an explanation as to why a 0 would be returned by this. Is it just when excel finds a blank cell?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is there might be different number of cells populated in $B:$B compared to $F:$F making OUID and Report different lengths which could screw up your index match function.